# How Do I align CSS Slider Switches without destroying them

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the CSS Slider Switches align.

I have attempted to use `position: absolute; margin-left: 15em` which normally does the trick ... but the sliders depend on not being `position: absolute;` and making them absolute destroys the visual effect of the slider.

I considered using a flex grid, but dont want the switches to ever wrap.

I could use a table, but I would like to avoid it if I could.

```css
/* toggle switch */
.switch{position:relative;display:inline-block;width:60px;height:34px}
.switch input{display:none}
.slider{position:absolute;cursor:pointer;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background-color:#555;-webkit-transition:.4s;transition:.4s}
.slider:before{position:absolute;content:"";height:26px;width:26px;left:4px;bottom:4px;background-color:#000;-webkit-transition:.4s;transition:.4s}input:checked+.slider{background-color:#fff}input:focus+.slider{box-shadow:0 0 1px #fff}input:checked+.slider:before{-webkit-transform:translateX(26px);-ms-transform:translateX(26px);transform:translateX(26px)}
.slider.round{border-radius:34px}
.slider.round:before{border-radius:50%}
```

```html
<div class="vfor-content">
  <span v-bind:id="item.name" onclick="_app.doFlipRelay(this.id)">
    <span>thing 1</span>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="item.value == '1'" disabled>
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="vfor-content">
  <span v-bind:id="item.name" onclick="_app.doFlipRelay(this.id)">
    <span>thing 2 with long name</span>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="item.value == '1'" disabled>
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="vfor-content">
  <span v-bind:id="item.name" onclick="_app.doFlipRelay(this.id)">
    <span>thing 3</span>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="item.value == '1'" disabled>
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, flex is a better way also to support easier vertical alignement but that requires reordering your DOM. If you want to keep this structure, probably the most easiest solution is to add a class to your span labels: `<span class="switch__title">thing 1</span>`

And then add:

```
.switch__title {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
```